# Modal Lightbox not centering on page

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

I've been working on a Bootstrap project and have a gallery page of images. When the user clicks on an image, a modal Lightbox should appear in the middle of the screen with the image. However, it is currently putting the image at the bottom of the screen, below all the other divs. It doesn't appear that any of the #lightbox CSS controls are getting applied when I inspect in the Chrome dev tools.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $('.lightbox-trigger').click(function(e) {
         
        //prevent default action (hyperlink)
        e.preventDefault();
         
        //Get clicked link href
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");
         
        /*  
        If the lightbox window HTML already exists in document, 
        change the img src to to match the href of whatever link was clicked
         
        If the lightbox window HTML doesn't exists, create it and insert it.
        (This will only happen the first time around)
        */
         
        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists
             
            //place href as img src value
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');
             
            //show lightbox window - you could use .show('fast') for a transition
            $('#lightbox').show('fast');
        }
         
        else { //#lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)
             
            //create HTML markup for lightbox window
            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
                '<p class="closeBtn">&times;</p>' +
                '<div id="content">' + //insert clicked link's href into img src
                    '<img src="' + image_href +'" />' +
                '</div>' +    
            '</div>';
                 
            //insert lightbox HTML into page
            $('body').append(lightbox);
          
        }
         $('.gallery-container').addClass('lightbox-active');
    });
     
    //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
    $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() { //must use on, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
        $('#lightbox').hide();
      $('.gallery-container').removeClass('lightbox-active');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

/* ///////////////////// NAVBAR //////////////////////// */
.navbar-style {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #333;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 10%;
}

.nav-custom img {
  width: 64px;
}

.icon-bar {
  background: white;
}

/* ///////////////////// NAVBAR //////////////////////// */

/* ///////////////////// MAIN AREA //////////////////////// */

.slogan h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.background-img img {
  width: 80%;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.blurb {
  font-family: 'League Script', cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

/* ///////////////////// FRONT GALLERY //////////////////////// */



.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px white;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

.flex-column {
  justify-content: space-between; /* have images appear as a four sided block */
  max-width: 250px;
}

/* LIGHTBOX OVERLAY */
#lighbox {
  position: fixed; 
/*  ^keeps lightbox window in the current viewport  */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  text-align: center;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

/* LIGHTBOX CLOSE BUTTON */
#lightbox .closeBtn {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

/* LIGHTBOX IMAGE */
#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  max-width: 940px;
}

/* BLUR BACKGROUND WHEN LIGHTBOX IS ACTIVE */
.lightbox-active {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1650px) {
  .flex-column {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}

img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="front-gallery">
      <div class="container-fluid gallery-container">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
          
<!--   ////////  1st COLUMN   ////////    -->    
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      FIRST IMAGE        -->
            <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/05/17/45/girl-2205813_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/05/17/45/girl-2205813_1280.jpg" alt="woman black and white photo" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
            
<!--      SECOND IMAGE        -->
            <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/13/18/10/woman-487090_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/13/18/10/woman-487090_1280.jpg" alt="dog" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
          </div>
          
<!--   ////////  2nd COLUMN   ////////    -->       
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      THIRD IMAGE        -->
       <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/13/00/black-1869685_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/13/00/black-1869685_1280.jpg" alt="woman color photo" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
<!--      FOURTH IMAGE        -->   
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/19/42/woman-659352_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/19/42/woman-659352_1280.jpg" alt="woman with tattoos" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  3rd COLUMN   ////////    -->     
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      FIFTH IMAGE        -->  
                 <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/11/person-828630_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/11/person-828630_1280.jpg" alt="outline of man photo" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
    
<!--      SIXTH IMAGE        -->   
     <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/27/17/52/model-2349037_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/27/17/52/model-2349037_1280.jpg" alt="woman under water" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
            </div>
          
<!--   ////////  4th COLUMN   ////////    -->              
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
 <!--      SEVENTH IMAGE        -->  
         <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/11/19/14/couple-1194312_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/11/19/14/couple-1194312_1280.jpg" alt="couple" class="img-fluid">
    </a>

<!--      EIGHTH IMAGE        -->  
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/03/10/34/studio-2913936_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/03/10/34/studio-2913936_1280.jpg" alt="woman smiling" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  5th COLUMN   ////////    -->             
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      NINTH IMAGE        -->    
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/14/04/08/selfie-1822563_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/14/04/08/selfie-1822563_1280.jpg" alt="kids taking selfie in field" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
    
<!--      TENTH IMAGE        -->  
                        <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/02/12/01/woman-6144753_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/02/12/01/woman-6144753_1280.jpg" alt="woman with eye makeup" class="img-fluid">
                          </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  6th COLUMN   ////////    -->             
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      ELEVENTH IMAGE        -->   
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/03/43/radio-1773304_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/03/43/radio-1773304_1280.jpg" alt="vintage radio" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
    
<!--      TWELFTH IMAGE        -->    
                        <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/24/01/16/photographer-819365_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/24/01/16/photographer-819365_1280.jpg" alt="outdoor photographer" class="img-fluid">
                          </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  7th COLUMN   ////////    -->             
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    
<!--      THITEENTH IMAGE        -->  
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/12/18/05/man-719228_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/12/18/05/man-719228_1280.jpg" alt="man thinking" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
    
<!--      FOURTEENTH IMAGE        -->   
                        <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/01/34/man-1866572_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/01/34/man-1866572_1280.jpg" alt="man with jacket" class="img-fluid">
                          </a>
            </div>
          
          
          </div> <!-- END FLEX ROW -->
      </div>  <!-- END CONTAINER -->
    </section>
```

Comment: because you're righting `lightbox` as `lighbox` in your CSS file

Comment: Typo in CSS? `#lighbox`

Comment: Kareem Dabbeet & Anurag Srivasteva, thank you! Second time a bloody misspelling has caused issues. Thank you for catching that!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a rule for #lightbox.

Use position absolute to put it in middle.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $('.lightbox-trigger').click(function(e) {
         
        //prevent default action (hyperlink)
        e.preventDefault();
         
        //Get clicked link href
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");
         
        /*  
        If the lightbox window HTML already exists in document, 
        change the img src to to match the href of whatever link was clicked
         
        If the lightbox window HTML doesn't exists, create it and insert it.
        (This will only happen the first time around)
        */
         
        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists
             
            //place href as img src value
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');
             
            //show lightbox window - you could use .show('fast') for a transition
            $('#lightbox').show('fast');
        }
         
        else { //#lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)
             
            //create HTML markup for lightbox window
            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
                '<p class="closeBtn">&times;</p>' +
                '<div id="content">' + //insert clicked link's href into img src
                    '<img src="' + image_href +'" />' +
                '</div>' +    
            '</div>';
                 
            //insert lightbox HTML into page
            $('body').append(lightbox);
          
        }
         $('.gallery-container').addClass('lightbox-active');
    });
     
    //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
    $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() { //must use on, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
        $('#lightbox').hide();
      $('.gallery-container').removeClass('lightbox-active');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

/* ///////////////////// NAVBAR //////////////////////// */
.navbar-style {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #333;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: 10%;
}

.nav-custom img {
  width: 64px;
}

.icon-bar {
  background: white;
}

/* ///////////////////// NAVBAR //////////////////////// */

/* ///////////////////// MAIN AREA //////////////////////// */

.slogan h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.background-img img {
  width: 80%;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.blurb {
  font-family: 'League Script', cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

/* ///////////////////// FRONT GALLERY //////////////////////// */



.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px white;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

.flex-column {
  justify-content: space-between; /* have images appear as a four sided block */
  max-width: 250px;
}

/* LIGHTBOX OVERLAY */
#lighbox {
  position: fixed; 
/*  ^keeps lightbox window in the current viewport  */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  text-align: center;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

/* LIGHTBOX CLOSE BUTTON */
#lightbox .closeBtn {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

/* LIGHTBOX IMAGE */
#lightbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
}

#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  max-width: 940px;
}

/* BLUR BACKGROUND WHEN LIGHTBOX IS ACTIVE */
.lightbox-active {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1650px) {
  .flex-column {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}

img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="front-gallery">
      <div class="container-fluid gallery-container">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
          
<!--   ////////  1st COLUMN   ////////    -->    
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      FIRST IMAGE        -->
            <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/05/17/45/girl-2205813_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/05/17/45/girl-2205813_1280.jpg" alt="woman black and white photo" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
            
<!--      SECOND IMAGE        -->
            <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/13/18/10/woman-487090_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/13/18/10/woman-487090_1280.jpg" alt="dog" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
          </div>
          
<!--   ////////  2nd COLUMN   ////////    -->       
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      THIRD IMAGE        -->
       <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/13/00/black-1869685_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/13/00/black-1869685_1280.jpg" alt="woman color photo" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
<!--      FOURTH IMAGE        -->   
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/19/42/woman-659352_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/19/42/woman-659352_1280.jpg" alt="woman with tattoos" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  3rd COLUMN   ////////    -->     
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      FIFTH IMAGE        -->  
                 <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/11/person-828630_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/11/person-828630_1280.jpg" alt="outline of man photo" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
    
<!--      SIXTH IMAGE        -->   
     <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/27/17/52/model-2349037_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/27/17/52/model-2349037_1280.jpg" alt="woman under water" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
            </div>
          
<!--   ////////  4th COLUMN   ////////    -->              
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
 <!--      SEVENTH IMAGE        -->  
         <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/11/19/14/couple-1194312_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/11/19/14/couple-1194312_1280.jpg" alt="couple" class="img-fluid">
    </a>

<!--      EIGHTH IMAGE        -->  
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/03/10/34/studio-2913936_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/03/10/34/studio-2913936_1280.jpg" alt="woman smiling" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  5th COLUMN   ////////    -->             
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      NINTH IMAGE        -->    
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/14/04/08/selfie-1822563_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/14/04/08/selfie-1822563_1280.jpg" alt="kids taking selfie in field" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
    
<!--      TENTH IMAGE        -->  
                        <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/02/12/01/woman-6144753_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/02/12/01/woman-6144753_1280.jpg" alt="woman with eye makeup" class="img-fluid">
                          </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  6th COLUMN   ////////    -->             
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
<!--      ELEVENTH IMAGE        -->   
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/03/43/radio-1773304_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/03/43/radio-1773304_1280.jpg" alt="vintage radio" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
    
<!--      TWELFTH IMAGE        -->    
                        <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/24/01/16/photographer-819365_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/24/01/16/photographer-819365_1280.jpg" alt="outdoor photographer" class="img-fluid">
                          </a>
            </div>
          
 <!--   ////////  7th COLUMN   ////////    -->             
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    
<!--      THITEENTH IMAGE        -->  
             <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/12/18/05/man-719228_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/12/18/05/man-719228_1280.jpg" alt="man thinking" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
    
<!--      FOURTEENTH IMAGE        -->   
                        <a style="display:contents" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/01/34/man-1866572_1280.jpg" class="lightbox-trigger">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/01/34/man-1866572_1280.jpg" alt="man with jacket" class="img-fluid">
                          </a>
            </div>
          
          
          </div> <!-- END FLEX ROW -->
      </div>  <!-- END CONTAINER -->
    </section>
```